# Composite Primary Key Index Maintenance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

Have a 3 part composite key Int, Int, Int on a large table 
Insert speed degrades due to fragmentation

PK1 does not fragment (inserts are in order and never revised)
But PK2,and PK3 fragment badly and quickly

What strategy should I use for index maintenance?

Is there a way to Rebuild the index with?

```
PK1 fill factor 100 
PK2 fill factor 10
PK3 fill factor 10
```

Comment: No - it's **ONE** index - you **cannot** have different fill factors on the columns of a single index ... the index structure is made up of entries of `(PK1, PK2, PK3)` and this tuple combined is stored on the pages. You can only set fill factors for the index/page - not for individual parts of a compound index....

Comment: @marc_s That is what I figured.  Should my strategy be 100 fill factor and just rebuild often.  Or should I try 50%.  Right now after two hours of loading that index is 60% fragmented.   I know what have you tried.  Is there a fill factor I should try.

Comment: Dropping your fillfactor that low is going to really increase the size of your indexes. This is probably not a good idea. Could you perhaps show us the table structures? Hard to tell exactly where the fragmentation comes in.  UPDATE: did not see previous comment ignore this one

Comment: My typical approach would be to use something like 70% or 80% on an index I suspect of fragmentation, and then just observe. See how fast and how badly it fragments. If it's unbearable later in the day - lower the fill factor even more. Typically, with 70-80% Fillfactor, you should be fine during the day, and if you rebuild those critical indexes every night, your system should work fine.

Comment: That literally is the table structure composite PK Int, Int, Int with not other data.  All have FK relationships.  PK1 is loaded in order.  PK2 and PK3 load random.  Will have about 10 rows for each PK1.  Load 1 PK1 at a time using insert values() () ().  I don't mind having that index big during the loads.  Once we get the data loaded will reindex at 100%

Comment: Tested at 50%, 80%, and 100% fill factor 100%  was fastest.  I am also loading to another database so not a conclusive test.  It would be cool to have different fill factors.   What I may do is hold that data in memory and then load the sorted data to SQL at the end of the load.

Comment: @marc_s If you will post as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it's ONE index - you cannot have different fill factors on the columns of a single index ... the index structure is made up of entries of `(PK1, PK2, PK3)` and this tuple combined is stored on the pages. You can only set fill factors for the index/page - not for individual parts of a compound index.

My typical approach would be to use something like 70% or 80% on an index I suspect of fragmentation, and then just observe. See how fast and how badly it fragments. If it's unbearable later in the day - lower the fill factor even more. Typically, with a 70-80% fill factor, you should be fine during the day, and if you rebuild those critical indexes every night, your system should work fine.